# Render a custom .jsx Component in $.ajax -ReactJS-

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have next:

```
export default class FormularioVerRespuestaInforme extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: APIBASENAME+"/delegado/informes/" + ObtenerParametroURL('id_informe') + "/entradas",
            data: "",
            type: "GET"
            //dataType: "JSON",
        })
        .done((respuesta) => {
            console.log(respuesta);
            $("#idDivContenedorInforme").append(
                <Caja title="f">
                    <textarea disabled id="idContenidoInforme" class="form-control" value="Hola esto es una prueba del informe y sus respuestas" required></textarea>
                </Caja>
            )
            //this.props.history.push(`/accion_realizada?estado=${respuesta.estado}&backTwice=true`);
        }).fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            console.log("XHR: ", xhr.responseText);
            //this.props.history.push(`/accion_realizada?estado=Incidencia Rechazada`);
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div id="idDivContenedorInforme" class="formularioRespuestasInforme"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Where `Caja` is a custom component, but it is not returned / renderized. I do not know how could I solve this... Any idea?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Perform a request, then update the state. let the state change cause the ui update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render that component conditionally use `state` variable, create a state variable with initial value of `false`, once you get the response update that value to `true` by using `setState`.

Write it like this:

```
export default class FormularioVerRespuestaInforme extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            show: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: APIBASENAME+"/delegado/informes/" + ObtenerParametroURL('id_informe') + "/entradas",
            data: "",
            type: "GET"
            //dataType: "JSON",
        })
        .done((respuesta) => {
            this.setState({show: true});
        }).fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            console.log("XHR: ", xhr.responseText);
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div id="idDivContenedorInforme" class="formularioRespuestasInforme">
                {this.state.show?
                    <Caja title="f">
                        <textarea disabled id="idContenidoInforme" class="form-control" value="Hola esto es una prueba del informe y sus respuestas" required></textarea>
                    </Caja>
                :
                    null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Update:**  `Caja` is a custom component, so instead of passing the textarea as children put that part inside `Caja` component only, if you want to pass some data (initial values) then pass those values only in `props`.

**Using map inside jsx:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
     super();
  }
  
  render(){
     return(
        <div>
          {
            [1,2,3,4,5].map(el => {
               return <div key={el}> Item: {el} </div>
            })
          }
        </div>
     )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: And if I would add more than one 'Caja'? I could save them into an array state right? But how could I do one 'Caja' for each item into that ArrayState? Thank you.

Comment: simply use a map on that state array to create caja components.

Comment: could you update your anwer with an example? I think into render you cant map, or yes?

Comment: yes we can use map to create the ui, check the updated answer :)

Comment: Oh!! A lot of Thanks! Instead I arrive at work I will try it and comment you if  it is working and UpVote and mark as Best Answer. Thank you again! :D

Comment: And a last anwer... How can add an element from ajax to my state? this.setState({MyArray: MyArray.push(item})?. Sorry for being so heavy

Comment: by element you mean data or html element? if Myaray is an `array` and item is any `object/array/value` then write it like this to update `state`: `let MyArray = [...this.state.MyArray];  MyArray.push(item);  this.setState({MyArray});`

Comment: ok! Thank you. all this must go into constructor? `constructor() { super(); this.state = { MyArray: let MyArray = [...this.state.MyArray]; MyArray.push(item); this.setState({MyArray})}`

Comment: OK, I will see!

Comment: I have tried it and it is working! Thank you so much! :D